# how to auto-fill text box with the dlookup function in access

Tags: ms-access, textbox, lookup

I am trying to auto-full a text box using the Dlookup function, as below:

```
=DLookUp("[CustomerFACT]![ID name]","CustomerFACT","[CustomerFACT]![ID number] = " & [Forms]![NewLoanForm_2]![ID number])
```

1. My original column names have spaces between them
2. It seems that the code works, only after I input an ID, it fills the text box with #Error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simpler syntax:

```
=DLookUp("[ID name]","[CustomerFACT]","[ID number] = " & [ID number] & "")
```

or, if `ID number` is text:

```
=DLookUp("[ID name]","[CustomerFACT]","[ID number] = '" & [ID number] & "'")
```

Comment: Then probably a field name is misspelled.

Comment: It's not; that's why I posted the full syntax and not the simple way to write... My columns are originally in hebrew, but it never made an issue...

Comment: Then the only option left is, that the control (textbox?) `[ID number]` does not exist. Try inserting a fixed number for this in the where clause.

Comment: So... I converted my original [ID Number] column from short text to number and it works! thank you so much!

Comment: Ah, that explains!